# Alternatives to XMLEncoder in Android Studio for writing objects to XML

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need to write an object to XML file in Android Studio and then get the values back. What functions do this? Are there any alternatives to [XMLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html)?

Additional Notes: I need XML Serialization for an Organizer app (Todo calendar app). I need to write events and dates in XML and then parse them from there and work with them (change, delete).

Comment: You should more explain what you need. It is not obvious for me.

Comment: updated the question below

Comment: @DaRezon For future reference, when you need to update a question, instead of posting additional info as an answer, hit the "edit" button just under your question. Then you can add the info there. That's how we keep things organized here.